# How to make view highlight like table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, highlight

I have a view with many subviews. I want all the views highlighted when user taps. I know I can loop through subviews and highlight them. But it's not elegant. So what's the best way I can achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the subviews have a different colour to the parent view? if not, then rather make the subviews backgrounds transparent, then when you need to highlight it, just highlight the parent view.

Comment: Sorry,every subview has different behavior. But thank you.

Comment: otherwise could try something using [key-value observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) but i think that would be more work than just looping, and possibly only marginally more elegant

Comment: I'm wondering what Apple did when table view cell was tapped . Loop through?

Comment: yeah probably looped through all subviews, not sure how they go about returning the background to its original state though for subviews when deselecting, maybe they store that info temporarily, but seems like a hassle

Answer (score 0):

Create an array containing all the views that should be highlighted. Then loop through the array to highlight them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class of UIView and follow the code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor YourColor];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor PreviousColor];
}
```